# how to do mathematical operation in html

Tags: javascript, html

i want show in percentage. im getting value like this 14.00

Expected value 56%.

14 is 56% of 25.

code

```
<h2>(@Model[1].filled.ToString("N2"))</h2>
```

Comment: This appears to be Razor, not just HTML. How would *you* get at an answer of 56 from a value of 14? Now write that expression here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript and do something like this...

```
var number1 = 14;
var number2 = 25;
var toPrint = (Math.floor((number1 / number2) * 100)) + "%";
```